# Need a detailed procedure to use meId diff with svn(subversion)

Tags: linux, svn

After a lot of search i could see that meId is a good diff tool for comparision in linux
I would like to use the meId for displaying the svn diff

I am new to linux as well as SVN

I just downloaded the meId and placed it on my desktop i am not sure what to do next ?

i could see 'svn diff -r 2165:2182 --diff-cmd meld' is used to do the trick

but i am not sure how to do this

Can some one guide me to get the diff of svn displayed in meID

Any help for this is greatly appreciated ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a wrapper script as described here: [SVN documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html#svn.advanced.externaldifftools.diff.ex-1)

In the Meld wiki you can find a wrapper script used to merge with Meld: [Meld wiki](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Meld?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=svn-merge-meld)

You can find the command line usage of Meld in the documentation.